# Adapt parameter pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, adapter

What is the different between Adapt Parameter Pattern VS Extract Interface?

According to [this ASP.net weblog](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/03/20/refactoring-adapt-parameter.aspx):

> Sometimes you are not able to use Extract Interface refactoring
>   because interface of parameter may be too large or there may be no
>   interface at all. You just have class to pass in and you are not able
>   to fake it or extend it to get class testable.

The only difference that I see in the code is: extracting the interface of passed class with different name and make it manually.

Could you please give me an example (eventually with source code) to highlight their differences in code in more detail?

Comment: What is your question? "Extract interface" is a *refactoring*, and I don't know a pattern that goes by the name of "Adapter **Parameter**", only "Adapter".

Comment: well,it should be Adapt parameter, but I can not see the differences between it and extract interface . http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/03/20/refactoring-adapt-parameter.aspx

Comment: It is not a pattern, it is another refactoring.

Comment: cool, what is its difference by extract interface , asp blog says when we can not extract interface we use it ... but as I see in its code, it use interface with another name ... thats make me confuse a little

Answer (score 1):

In the [ExtractInterface](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/02/28/refactoring-extract-interface.aspx) article, the author creates *an interface* and *a mock implementation*.

in the [Adapt Parameter](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/03/20/refactoring-adapt-parameter.aspx) article, the author creates *an interface*, *a mock implementation* and **a wrapper implemenation**.  The original class is adapted/wrapped, because the original class can't be modified for some reason.  One could say (if they read the article backwards), that first he Adapted the Parameter (by wrapping it), and then Extracted the Interface from the wrapper.